# How do I start the Privacy and Activity Manager from command line?

Tags: unity, command-line, system-settings

This is the "Security & Privacy" dialogue in System Settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be what you're looking for:

```
gnome-control-center activity-log-manager &
```