# Recent Items missing Zeitgeist

Tags: zeitgeist

I want to delete history and disable recent items recording. So i went to Zeitgeist options, but there is no Recent Items or Files tab only 'Security', 'Search' and 'Diagnostics' tab. But in my guest session there is Files and Folders tab, but in user session its missing Please help important.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: The latest version of ubuntu (13.10)

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 12.04 (and above), you can start the Privacy and Activity Manager [from command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384827/how-do-i-start-the-privacy-and-activity-manager-from-command-line/384831#384831), type *privacy* in the Dash or any of the way that you prefer.

Here's a snap of the manager window.
[image: snap1]

Comment: Yeah, but this tab 'Recent Items' is missing in my os. Only 'security', 'search' and 'diagnostics'. Here's a snap

[IMG]http://i.imgur.com/nyWUYk1.png?1[/IMG]